# Retrive latest directory

Tags: python, directory

```
import paramiko
ssh =paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(hostname='test.com',username='test',password='test123')
srcpath = ('/tmp/test/')
destpath = ('/tmp/file/')
transfer=ssh.open_sftp()
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('cd /tmp/test/; ls -1t *txt* | head -1') 
out = stdout.read().splitlines()
print out
error = stderr.read().splitlines()
print error
transfer.close()
ssh.close()
```

Above is my code, i tried to retrieve the latest directory on remote server. I am facing below error.

**Error:**

> ['bash: head: command not found']

is there any other way to retrieve latest directory ?

Comment: Check your destination system has `head` command installed

Comment: Head and tail command is not installed. Is there any another alternate way to find out the latest directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually don't need "head" nor "tail", just access the last line from python as follows.
*This is your code little edited to catch the last line as* `last_line`:

```
import paramiko
ssh =paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(hostname='test.com',username='test',password='test123')
srcpath = ('/tmp/test/')
destpath = ('/tmp/file/')
transfer=ssh.open_sftp()
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('cd /tmp/test/; ls -1t *txt*') 
out = stdout.read().splitlines()
last_line = out[-1] ## takes out the last line without need for tail command
print out
print last_line
error = stderr.read().splitlines()
print error
transfer.close()
ssh.close()
```

Comment: If i go for above option, it's not picking the latest file. I want latest file which was included in that folder

Comment: what do you mean by '*latest*'? that code simply gets the 'last' file (as sorted by your 'ls') and takes the last. You have to play with `ls` and its options to find the one that suits your definition of latest. for 'my' definition, that is latest in terms of edit time, the correct syntax is `ls -tr1`